# Why I'm getting null on textmeshpro text?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When the game start the TextMeshPro text is empty :

[image: Text is empty at start]

At the top :

```
public TextMeshPro text;
```

Then :

```
if (primaryTarget != null)
        {
            if (displayDescriptionText == true)
            {
                descriptionTextImage.SetActive(true);
                displayDescriptionText = false;
            }
            text.SetText(primaryTarget.description);
            
        }
        else
        {
            text.SetText("");
            descriptionTextImage.SetActive(false);
        }
```

The null is on the line :

```
text.SetText("");
```

before that I tried :

```
text.text = "";
```

Comment: I can't even drag in the editor the TextMeshPro object to the text field.  I can't reference to the text of the TextMeshPro. I tried also only Text text but then also can't drag the TextMeshPro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong Class Type.

`TextMeshPro` is the 3D object renderer.

You want `TextMeshProUGUI`, which is the UI renderer.